# STM32 Ethernet custom hardware

Tags: ethernet

I'm having a problem getting the ethernet interface of an STM32H745 to work.

This is my circuit:[image]

I got a nucleo-h745zi-q which has an MCU very similar to mine, and an ethernet interface practically identical to mine, on the nucleo-h745zi-q everything works, while on my customs hardware it doesn't even ping.

What could it be?
It could be a non-compatible RJ45 connector, non-compatible TVS diodes etc etc...

This is my layout (the pulldown to LED2 which is on the other PCB side, everything else is on the top layer).

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you certain it's a hardware issue?  If so, how?  With my limited exposure to ST's devices, it is my impression that the STM32H's Ethernet firmware setup and implementation is a complicated beast.

Comment: Hardware seems correct at first glance. I would go with @ChrisKnudsen recommendation of investigating the firmware side.

Comment: Please cross-check your schematic with that of the original board. If no problem/mismatch is found, test your PCB with a multimeter. There might be a broken trace somewhere.

Comment: Is there a ground connection on the ePad?

Comment: @Justme What do you mean by ePad?

Comment: @FedericoMassimi Pin 25 is the only ground, and it's the exposed metal pad under the IC. Have you soldered it to PCB and is it connected to ground?

Comment: @justme OKOK, yes, is the PIN 25 in the schematic.